# Adding data into embedded array - The field must be an array but is of type object in document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying to add array to an existing array in a document but get the error :

```
'The field 'pnrs' must be an array but is of type object in document'.
```

Not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong...

I have this structure in my collection :

```
{
    "flightName" : "BA1304:2020-05-25",
    "flightInfo" : {
            "flightNumber" : "BA1304",
            "flightDate" : "2020-05-25",
            "airline" : "British Airways",
            "departCode" : "LHR",
            "arriveCode" : "ABZ"
    },
    "pnrs" :
            {
                    "bookingReference" : "MGE60M",
                    "passengers" :
                            {
                                    "passportNumber" : "12345678",
                                    "issueCountry" : "GBR",
                                    "issueDate" : "2020-05-01",
                                    "expiryDate" : "2020-05-01",
                                    "emailAddress" : "johndoe@email.com",
                                    "name" : {
                                            "firstName" : "Jon",
                                            "surname" : "Doe",
                                            "dob" : "1980-05-07"
                                    },
                                    "address" : {
                                            "address1" : "31 High Street",
                                            "address2" : "",
                                            "city" : "London",
                                            "code" : "SE10 8BD",
                                            "country" : "United Kingdom"
                                    },
                                    "creditCard" : {
                                            "creditCardNumber" : "4929109468047005",
                                            "cardType" : "creditCard",
                                            "ccExpiryDate" : "2021-05-01",
                                            "ccIssueDate" : "2018-04-01"
                                    }
                            }
            }
}
```

and I want to add another array in 'pnrs' :

```
{
                    "bookingReference" : "XB6RD9",
                    "passengers" :
                            {
                                    "passportNumber" : "98658421",
                                    "issueCountry" : "GBR",
                                    "issueDate" : "20217-08-01",
                                    "expiryDate" : "2027-08-01",
                                    "emailAddress" : "bill.smith@someemail.com",
                                    "name" : {
                                            "firstName" : "Bill",
                                            "surname" : "Smith",
                                            "dob" : "1962-01-14"
                                    },
                                    "address" : {
                                            "address1" : "22 Bridge Street",
                                            "address2" : "",
                                            "city" : "Glasgow",
                                            "code" : "G3 6EF",
                                            "country" : "United Kingdom"
                                    },
                                    "creditCard" : {
                                            "creditCardNumber" : "432187651234",
                                            "cardType" : "creditCard",
                                            "ccExpiryDate" : "2022-02-01",
                                            "ccIssueDate" : "2020-01--01"
                                    }
                            }
            }
```

I have tried :

```
db.collection.update( { flightName: "BA1304:2020-05-25" },
{$push:
    {pnrs:
            {
                    "bookingReference" : "XB6RD9",
                    "passengers" :
                            {
                                    "passportNumber" : "98658421",
                                    "issueCountry" : "GBR",
                                    "issueDate" : "20217-08-01",
                                    "expiryDate" : "2027-08-01",
                                    "emailAddress" : "bill.smith@someemail.com",
                                    "name" : {
                                            "firstName" : "Bill",
                                            "surname" : "Smith",
                                            "dob" : "1962-01-14"
                                    },
                                    "address" : {
                                            "address1" : "22 Bridge Street",
                                            "address2" : "",
                                            "city" : "Glasgow",
                                            "code" : "G3 6EF",
                                            "country" : "United Kingdom"
                                    },
                                    "creditCard" : {
                                            "creditCardNumber" : "432187651234",
                                            "cardType" : "creditCard",
                                            "ccExpiryDate" : "2022-02-01",
                                            "ccIssueDate" : "2020-01--01"
                                    }
                            }
            }
}
}
)
```

But I get 'The field 'pnrs' must be an array but is of type object in document'

Comment: pnrs is not an array so you can't push into it. You have to make pnrs an array field.

Comment: OK, thanks - I have added the [ ] to make pnrs an array, I no longer get the error, but I'm still not able to push an entry into the pnrs array. I use the same $push command as above and now I just get :

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Comment: The syntax looks correct. You can try a [$push examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#examples), and see if it is working.